# How big does the Schottky Barrier or Band Offset have to be for a junction to be a diode?

Tags: current, diodes, rectifier

Current rectification happens when there is a large Schottky Barrier or a large Conduction band offset (excluding cases such as tunnel diodes). My question is, how large (in electron volts) does the barrier or offset have to be? I know that the answer is not definite, but I would like to know a range, similar as to how we call any material with a band gap of 1-3 eV a semiconductor.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "anything"; however, that does not mean that it is useful as a diode.  All of the "ohmic" contacts on a semiconductor are actually very thin eV barriers.  If I put a metal plug down to polysilicon, I get a Schottky contact, but then I keep increasing doping until the barrier is thin enough to look like a resistor due to the small energy barrier potential.